# List comprehension instead of lambda in DataFrame.apply()?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I've seen it said ([artima.com](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) and [python-course.eu](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php)) that no less an luminary than Guido wanted to remove lambda from Python, suggesting that same results could be achieved using list comprehension.  As someone learning Python and struggling to come to grips with lambdas and list comprehensions I (so far) favour the latter.
The python-course page detailed above goes on to demonstrate use of lambda functions, and I can in fact rewrite the examples provided using list comprehension.
E.g.

```
C = [39.2, 36.5, 37.3, 38, 37.8]
F1 = list(map(lambda x: (x *1.8) + 32, TC))
F2 = [(x *1.8) + 32 for x in TC]
```

in which F1 and F2 each return

```
[102.56, 97.7, 99.14, 100.4, 100.03999999999999]
```

In these cases, I agree list comprehension can be used instead of lambda, and I comprehend them better to boot!

Now in working with the DataFrame.apply() function I have been stymied in my attempts to come up with an alternative to lambda using list comprehension. Take

```
G = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1992, 1996, 1999], 'winner':['Pakistan',\
        'Sri Lanka','Australia']}, columns = ['year','winner'])
```

which gives

```
   year     winner
0  1992   Pakistan
1  1996  Sri Lanka
2  1999  Australia
```

If I wish to manipulate series data, in this case to reformat the year, a lambda function works:

```
G['year'] = G['year'].apply(lambda x: "'{:02d}".format(x % 100))
```

returning,

```
  year     winner
0  '92   Pakistan
1  '96  Sri Lanka
2  '99  Australia
```

and I can't figure out a way to do this using list comprehension.
Out of academic curiosity, is there a way?
Or is the assertion "There is an equally powerful alternative to lambda, filter, map and reduce, i.e. list comprehension" false?

Comment: Note the position of `lambda` in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
G['year'] = ["'{:02d}".format(x % 100) for x in G.year]
```

?

Comment: Looks very sensible.  That's how I would do it.

Comment: That is beautiful, my mental model was stuck on the "must use apply()" train

Comment: Though now I'm still curious (academically) about whether there is always a way to replace a `lambda` with an equivalent list comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand, the argument isn't that `lambda` can be replaced by *list comprehensions*, it was that the combination of `map` and `filter` -
 usually involving `lambda` - have direct equivalents with list-comprehensions. E.G.

```
list(map(int, list_of_str)) == [int(s) for s in list_of_str]
```

Or using both filtering and mapping much more cleanly:

```
list(map(lambda x:x**2, filter(lambda x: x%2==0, mylist)))
```

Is equivalent to

```
[x**2 for x in mylist if x%2==0]
```

`lambda` creates a *function object*, list-comprehensions create *list objects*. A `lambda` can be replaced by a full function definition:

```
def format_mod(x): 
    return "'{:02d}".format(x % 100)

G['year'].apply(format_mod)
```

The **only** advantage to `lambda` is that it is *anonymous*, i.e., it doesn't have to be assigned to a name.

Comment: I agree, I can't find evidence that Guido argued all lambdas could be replaced by list comprehensions, but http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196 confirms he did want to get rid of `lambda` (as well as `map` and `filter` and https://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php states this was his reasoning. The latter may be faulty in that in the former Guido argues lambdas can be replaced by nested functions.

Comment: @James no, you don't understand, Guido did not argue that lambdas can be replaced by list comprehensions at all. All he was saying was that the very common use-case of using `lambda` *in combination* with `map` and `filter` already has a better alternative

Comment: I'm not sure what you just disagreed with? At any rate, I'm curious as to the assertion that lambdas are unnecessary, for which I have cited evidence that Guido once held this opinion.  I freely admit I am a poor padawan (maybe not even that) in this field.  But I'm curious, are there uses of lambda functions that do not have other pythonic alternatives?

Comment: @James when you said "I can't find evidence that Guido argued all lambdas could be replaced by list comprehensions", seems to imply to me that you are seeing list-comprehensions as a replacement for `lambda` in at least some cases, or that the python-course link is implying that, but they are orthogonal concepts. That is all I'm trying to emphasize.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, yes that was my original understanding, which I did modify after re-reading the references and seeing what Guido said vs what someone else suggested he said. At any rate, I'm curious if you can point me to uses for lambda that don't have a reasonable alternative?  I can see why many may find it preferable to have  a lambda rather than a full function definition, but so far the examples I'm seeing don't need either; I'm looking for examples where use of lambda is necessary or advantageous.

Comment: @James there is one, and only one, use for a `lambda` that a full function definition cannot achieve: creating an anonymous function. But you never really *need* an anonymous function, it can just be handy sometimes.